# How do I add a trusted CA chain in Envoy Gateway?

Tags: kubernetes

I am just starting out trying to configure Envoy Gateway.

I followed the quickstart and got it installed and working pretty quickly. It created a load balancer for me and I can access my service behind it.

I wanted to add jwt auth in front of the service so I added a `SecurityPolicy` with the appropriate config containing my jwks URL

```
...
  jwt:
    providers:
      - name: buildkite
        remoteJWKS:
          uri: https://agent.buildkite.com/.well-known/jwks
```

However, once applied, I get errors in the log trying to access that URL:

```
[2023-12-07 05:36:29.436][1][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:278] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"19"] closing socket: 0
[2023-12-07 05:36:29.436][1][debug][connection] [source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:241] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"19"] remote address:108.139.10.123:443,TLS_error:|268436496:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE|268435610:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO:TLS_error_end:TLS_error_end
```

[Envoy docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/quick-start/securing#validate-an-endpoint-s-certificates-when-connecting) suggest that this might be because it does not validate certs by default.

Is my assumption correct?  And if yes, what resource do I need to modify to add TLS support.

Envoy Proxy doco suggests something along the lines of:

```
validation_context:
  trusted_ca:
    filename: certs/cacert.pem
```

...but if add this to my gateway Deployment then it fails to start.